# Disallow/remove shutdown/restart options on Xfce4

Tags: x11, rhel8

I am using a RHEL8 server system as jumphost - connection to it from the windows-world with tls 1.2/rdp and then Xcfe4 as X11 base for applications in need of X-windows.

My questions are about the poweroff-button on the upper right corner of Xfce4.

1. How to I inhibt users from powering off / reboot when there is only one logged in user?
2. How do I replace that button with a logout-button?

**xfce** is version 4.16, **polkit** is version 0.115

With CentOS/RHEL7 this was no problem - you just had to create a kioskrc:
*/etc/xdg/xfce/kiosk/kioskrc*:

```
[xfce4-session]
Shutdown=root
```

I assume that 1. has to do with polkit (some findings from 2012 go into that direction), so I included its version.

Comment: #1 is solved via polkit.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for question #1 is via polkit:

**/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/** set all items corresponding to hybernate/shutdown/reboot to
"no" in these two files:

- org.xfce.power.policy
- org.freedesktop.login1.policy